# PPL when_all with tasks of different types?

Tags: c++, tbb, ppl

I'd like to use PPL "when_all" on tasks with different types. And add a "then" call to that task.

But when_all returns task that takes a vector, so all elements have to be the same type. So how do I do this?

This is what I have come up with but it feels like a bit of a hack:

```
//3 different types:
int out1;
float out2;
char out3;

//Unfortunately I cant use tasks with return values as the types would be  different ...
auto t1 = concurrency::create_task([&out1](){out1 = 1; }); //some expensive operation
auto t2 = concurrency::create_task([&out2](){out2 = 2; }); //some expensive operation
auto t3 = concurrency::create_task([&out3](){out3 = 3; }); //some expensive operation

auto t4 = (t1 && t2 && t3); //when_all doesnt block

auto t5 = t4.then([&out1, &out2, &out3](){
    std::string ret = "out1: " + std::to_string(out1) + ", out2: " + std::to_string(out2) + ", out3: " + std::to_string(out3);
    return ret;
});
auto str = t5.get();

std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Anyone got a better idea?

(parallel_invoke blocks so I dont want to use that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task groups will work.

Failing that:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct get_many{
  std::tuple<task<Ts>...> tasks;
  template<class T0, size_t...Is>
  std::tuple<T0,Ts...>
  operator()(
    std::task<T0> t0,
    std::index_sequence<Is...>
  ){
    return std::make_tuple(
      t0.get(),
      std::get<Is>(tasks).get()...
    );
  }
  template<class T0>
  std::tuple<T0,Ts...>
  operator()(task<T0> t0){
    return (*this)(
      std::move(t0),
      std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}
    );
  }
};

template<class T0, class...Ts>
task<std::tuple<T0,Ts...>> when_every(
  task<T0> next, task<Ts>... later
){
  return next.then( get_many<Ts...>{
    std::make_tuple(std::move(later)...)
  } );
}
```

which doesn't work with `void` tasks, but otherwise bundles any set of tasks into a task of tuples.

Getting `void`s to work is a bit more work.  One way would be to write a `get_safe` that returns `T` for `task<T>` and `void_placeholder` for `task<void>`, then filter the resulting tuple before returning.  Or write a `partition_args` that splits args into `task<void>` and `task<T>`, and act differently on the two of them.  Both are a bit of a headache.  We could also do a tuple-append pattern (where we deal with the tasks one-at-a-time, and can either append a `T` to the `tuple` or do nothing for `void`).

It uses two C++14 library features (index_sequence and index_sequence_for) but both are easy to write in C++11 (2-4 lines each), and implementations are easy to find.

I forget if task is copyable, I assumed it was not in the above code.  If it is copyable, a shorter version of the above code will work.  Apologies for any typos.

Comment: Thanks. tuple instead of vector makes a nice interface. I might be wrong here, but I'm under the impression that I should avoid calling get (or wait). As they block and kill scalability. So implementing a custom "when_all" that calls "get" under the covers seems wrong to me. Looking at the implementation of concurrency::when_all, it looks like "get" is only called after all tasks are completed so it will not block. But I'm out of my depth here. Finally I'm not sure how I can chain and join task continuations together in a non blocking fashion.

Comment: @someone the `get` is only called within a `then`, and the `then` code is run asynchronously (I assume, as it returns a `task`), hopefully in the thread of the first task.